# Intercept call made using TAPI

Tags: c#, .net, tapi

I have an application which currently has an option to call phone numbers. Now by default it opens the Windows Phone dialler utility and tries to call the number.

I want it to instead make the call using skype, so what I was thinking was to create a c# application which would capture the callRequest and instead call skype.exe /callto:

Has anyone done anything like this before?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not in a neat way. You can probably intercept the call but the calling application would probably act like an error has happened.

Here's an old discussion about just this in the TAPI newsgroup:

http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Development/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.tapi/2004-03/0347.html